# Heter to Work on 9 b’Av But No Bracha

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, tisha-bav, shulchan-aruch

Shulchan Aruch 554:23 says one is permitted to work even before chazot if he will lose money.  554:24 says he will not see a siman bracha from that work.

Why would the mechaber go out of his way to allow work for davar ha’aveid yet say there is no siman bracha for that work which he is allowing?

Why would anyone want to follow this Halacha then if there is no siman bracha for this work?

What is the purpose of the heter of the work and for someone to waste his time doing the work if it won’t produce a siman bracha?

Comment: To me it seems that not to loose is one thing, and no-brocho means that you will not gain. So it seems if you work it might help you not to loose but you will not gain

Comment: For example one's freazer broke and his food is getting ruined, he can work to save this food (by putting it into another freezer) no problems. but if he will also will process the food to make it better, (cost more) then this "increase" will not being him profit  (brocho) in the long run

Comment: Is the only purpose of working to produce simanei bracha? Usually people work for money or food.

Comment: @DoubleAA What then exactly is the nature of this siman bracha?  If the only purpose of working is to make money, why does the mechaber throw in this additional element of siman bracha and how is it different than the money one earns from working in any case?  Isn’t all our money and parnassah ultimately decreed and provided by H and a bracha in its own right?  What does the siman bracha add?